# Is writing same value to same file by multiple threads thread-safe?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, file-descriptor

I have C program that is executed by multiple threads from multiple processes.
Threads write the same value to beginning the file. **Is it thread safe?**

**For example when writing "0". I expect the file to contain just "0" not "00" or anything else.**

The following test passes. But I need to be 100% sure.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *ThreadFunction(void *ptr)
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        const int Concurrent_fd = open("/dev/ConcurrencyTest.txt", O_RDWR);

        char* Value = "0";
        write(Concurrent_fd, Value, strlen(Value));

        close(Concurrent_fd);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    static const int NbThreads = 50;
    pthread_t Threads[NbThreads];

    for(int i=0; i<NbThreads; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&Threads[i], NULL, ThreadFunction, NULL);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<NbThreads; ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(Threads[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

Compiled with gcc:
gcc -pthread -o program-output Test.c

Comment: You need to error-check every system call you have used. Don't write code like this. On Windows the `open()` may fail if concurrent with another.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to think about here:

- are the library calls you are using listed as MT-Safe?
- Is the function that you are calling in all of these threads reentrant?
- In the case of writing to a file, what happens when you try to open a file that is open already?

#### Are the library calls you are using listed as MT-Safe?

In your case, the simple answer is yes. `open`, `close`, and `write` are all listed as MT-Safe in the GNU libc Reference Manual

#### Is the function that you are calling reentrant?

This just means that the function doesn't have static or global memory access that could get messed up by calling it in the middle of it being called. `strtok` vs `strtok_r` is a classic example, where `strtok` uses static variables to get the job done so it is listed as "MT-Unsafe race:strtok" and `strtok_r` does the same task by using function arguments passed by reference and allowing the user to manage the data. This allows you to split `strtok_r` calls across multiple threads as long as you keep the data being passed to it thread specific.

Your function is reentrant because it has no persistent data

#### What happens if a thread calls open while another thread has that file open

I would modify your code to check for a return value of -1 from `open`, which would then copy the value of `errno` immediately and write it to `stderr` or `stdout`. Use `perror` or `error` to write it out so you see the error message in human readable text. Be careful to save `errno` before doing anything else if you detect a return of -1 so something else doesn't set `errno`. Luckily `errno` is thread safe, and each thread gets its own global `errno`.

Something like this:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    void *ThreadFunction(void * thread_num)
    {
        char * error_message; 
        if(0 > asprintf(&error_message, "Open error in thread %d", (int)thread_num))
            perror("asprintf error");

        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {

            const int Concurrent_fd = open("/dev/ConcurrencyTest.txt", O_RDWR);
            if(Concurrent_fd == -1)
                perror(error_message);

            char* Value = "0";
            write(Concurrent_fd, Value, strlen(Value));

            close(Concurrent_fd);
        }

        free(error_message);
        return NULL;
    }

int main()
    {
        static const int NbThreads = 50;
        pthread_t Threads[NbThreads];

        for(int i=0; i<NbThreads; ++i)
        {
            pthread_create(&Threads[i], NULL, ThreadFunction, (void *)i);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<NbThreads; ++i)
        {
            pthread_join(Threads[i], NULL);
        }
    }
```

I suspect that the operating system is doing the heavy lifting here and is blocking some threads from opening the file simultaneously. Another indication of this would be having less than 500 writes completed in the file.

For more details please refer to the man pages regarding [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and [close(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html), especially the section in close about multi-threaded behavior

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping :). I tried with 500 threads and it still works on both Windows and Linux. If I understand well points 1 and 2 are good. However(point 3) there is no guarantee that opening the file from different threads will give the expected behavior.

Comment: I'm no expert on the way the Linux kernel or windows handles flagging files as they are being edited (between open and close calls) but I suppose my expectation was that a flag would be set somewhere by the OS. On points 1 and 2 you are right, the way it is written is thread safe.

Comment: I added an additional edit with links to thean pages for open and close. I'd read the sections regarding multi-threaded behavior and try to understand the benefit of O_CLOEXEC.

Comment: `open()`, `write()`, and `close()` are not library functions, they are system calls, which are atomic by definition.

Comment: In POSIX, unless you use `O_EXCL` or some kind of file locking, you can open the file mulitple times and each open will give an independent file descriptor (at least until you run out of file descriptors).